# Oracle converted Varchar field to number how to convert it back to Varchar

Tags: oracle

Till today we use to enter numeric value in the Varchar column so Oracle converted that varchar field to Numeric field.
And now when we are trying to insert Character value it is throwing ORA-01722 (invalid number).

Could anyone help me out in order to convert it back to varchar field?

Comment: Post the table description and the query that threw the exception

Comment: And what do you mean by *Oracle converted that varchar field to Numeric field*?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask], and post relevant details.  Thanks.

Comment: Who is Oracle who converted a varchar field to numeric field? Do you have a DBA or a developer whose name is the same as the company (Oracle)? Or are you saying that the company itself changed the data type of a column in a table in your database? That seems pretty difficult to believe.

Answer (score 0):

The commenters are correct: the database does not change column types on its own. In general, you must create a new column, copy the old data over to the new column, drop the original column, and rename the new column.

```
drop table deleteme_table;

-- zippy s/b varchar2(30), not integer
CREATE TABLE deleteme_table
(
    adate       DATE
  , zippy   INTEGER
);

-- Add the correct type to the table as a new column
ALTER TABLE deleteme_table
    ADD (tempcol VARCHAR2 (30));

-- Copy the old values to the new column
UPDATE deleteme_table
   SET tempcol   = zippy;

-- Get rid of the original column
ALTER TABLE deleteme_table
    DROP COLUMN zippy;

-- Rename to original column name   
alter table deleteme_table rename column tempcol to zippy;
```